# Fetch data from dynamic list of tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of tables from multiple database schemas.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME,TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN('incentives','winner') AND TABLE_SCHEMA!='federated'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
 $databases[]=$row['TABLE_SCHEMA'];
 $tables[]=$row['TABLE_NAME'];
}
```

I have used these tables to create federated tables on a separate database

```
 foreach(array_keys($databases) as $key){
  $db=$databases[$key];
  $tb=$tables[$key];

 $createserver=mysql_query("CREATE SERVER  $db
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
OPTIONS (USER 'root', HOST 'localhost', PORT 3306, DATABASE '$db')");

 $insertWinners= mysqli_query($connection,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tb (
`iid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `incentive` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `winner` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mpesa` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `ddate` date NOT NULL,
  `stato` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flag` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='$db/$tb'") ; 
}
```

The federated tables have the same structure but with different names and data.These federated tables are expected to grow dynamically.To fetch data from the tables i can use union statement like:

```
mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM incentive_winners UNION SELECT * FROM d1_incentive_winners UNION SELECT * FROM d2_incentive_winners");
```

The above query is subsequently used to create a view. 
So, With the list of tables set to grow. How can i query the database without having to append another UNION?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design (although, with your knowledge of database nomenclature, it seems probable that you knew that already)

Comment: @Strawberry....thats is probable but circumstances cant allow alteration of the current design...I have to find a way to work around it